# GA Search and Replace Filter - Consolidate URLs

Tags: google-analytics

I have been trying to remove all the "?area=rgm_xxxx"in the end of my urls by using the Search and Replace Filter in GA so the urls for the same page can be consolidated. For example, I have an url "www.myurl/home/?area=rgm_home_topnav&button=home" and "www.myurl/home/?area=rgm_article_topnav&button=home". How can I consolidate them into "www.myurl/home/"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get rid of url parameters there may be no need to use a filter, you could add them to the list of 'Exclude URL Query Parameters' in view settings.

Failing that you could use an advanced filter using regex to change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Does that mean analytics will consolidate those urls moving forward, or will it group all data collected under those urls?  I have some mapped urls (http://www.example.com/ProductLine maps to http://www.example.com/ProductLine.aspx, so I have stats for both urls).  I did a search and replace filter, and it showed how it would impact stats, but when I look at the behavior drilldown it does not apply the filter.  Does it just not apply it there, but it will elsewhere?

Comment: It will consolidate those urls moving forward, you can't retrospectively change the data in the free version of GA.
It should apply everywhere.